# Alias of find returns find: paths must precede expression:

Tags: bash, find, alias

**I have a script "fd.sh"

./fd.sh $1 never fails

Below is the script:**

/~ 2 07:53 AM :> cat fd.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo -e '\n'

find . -maxdepth 3   -iname "*$1*.*" -type f -exec wc -c "{}" ;

**My alias in bash_aliases is**

fdx='find . -maxdepth 3   -iname "*$1*.*" -type f -exec wc -c "{}" '

**When I run the alias looking for all files from my home directory with the string "WORK", I get the message below:**

/~ 1 07:51 AM :> fdx WORK
find: paths must precede expression:    WORK
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
/~ 1 07:51 AM :>

**It appears to me the two commands are identical, but only the script works, meaning I have to copy the script to parent directory of the folder I am searching.  Cannot search in / as that would take days.  Leaving my little find scripts all over the servers would also make the admins very unhappy

THX.**

Answer (score 1):

`alias`es only adds your parameters after the `alias`ed command.
If you want to insert the parameters somewhere inside the command, you can create a function.

Example that invokes `wc` with a number of files at a time:

```bash
fdx() { find . -maxdepth 3 -iname "$1.*" -type f -exec wc -c {} + ; }
```

If you prefer to invoke `wc` one time per found file:

```bash
fdx() { find . -maxdepth 3 -iname "$1.*" -type f -exec wc -c {} \; ; }
```